# How to write Java code to Spring Configuration File

Tags: java, xml, caching, spring-security

I have a spring configuration file for spring security. At beginning my file is getting from cache and when I do an operation it redirects me to the login page (However I can see page at first.) I want to solve that cache problem like that:

```
<beans:property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/index.html?Math.random()"/>
```

However I think that it is not doing what I want, I am not sure.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can't do that....you already know the answer, because it doesn't work.

Comment: @duffymo Spring Expression language does that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using Spring [expression language](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html)

```
<property name="url" value="#{'/index.html?' + T(java.lang.Math).random()}"/>
```

Comment: It gives me error: `Field or property 'Math' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext'`